# Resize items of RecyclerView (ConstraintLayout, Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm working on this app that has a RecyclerView and I want to resize the items so they all can fit within it, without the need of scrolling.

[Right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtKU8.png) looks like a want because it only has 3 elements, but I need it to be able to show up to 12 (and all of them need to be visible without scrolling!), meaning that if there are 9 elements, those should shrink enough so all of them have the same size and fit within the Recycler.

Is there a way to rescale the items without resizing them manually? I'm about to do it in the Adapter (depending on the `itemList.size` they will have X or Y padding, margins, etc.). I don't like it at all but I haven't found anything else yet.

I'm using **ConstraintLayout** and **Kotlin**.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't want scrolling, why are you using _RecyclerView_?

Comment: you should use simple LinearLayout for that add the views to that LinearLayout and give the child views a weight. Do not use RecyclerView unless you want scrolling behavior.

Comment: Well, because I thought the recycler was the tool to display N items, as it's an upgraded version of ListView-GridView, didn't know that the main feature was the scroll. What should I use then? I've been told that nesting layouts (specially Linear) can affect the efficiency of the app.

Comment: Try [_ConstraintLayout_](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout). It promotes a flat view hierarchy and it looks like you may be able to use it using a horizontal chain with weights (like _LinearLayout_) and, maybe, some resizable text.

Comment: use https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout